# How can I display newest post outside the loop in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, loops, post

how can I display and create box with newest post outside the loop in Wordpress? I showed this on the picture in this link http://i.imgur.com/UbBvlnE.png. I'm talking about this in the red frame ;)
Sorry for my english.

I use a Masonry CSS for all my post on homepage http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/

This is a code for the loop:

```
<div class="all_center">
<?php query_posts($query_string."&orderby=post_date"); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


<?php the_post_thumbnail('mediumImageCropped'); ?>
                        <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<div class="postmetadata">


                        </div>
</div>
</div>


        <?php endwhile; ?>



        <?php else : ?>

                <h2>Not Found</h2>

        <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what you've done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) );

echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent_posts[0]['ID'], 'thumbnail'); 

echo $recent_posts[0]['post_content'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but now my post is duplicate. It is outside the loop in the newest box and in the loop. This is look like it http://i.imgur.com/8NyFqLt.png

Comment: Yes you can use this code outside of loop, and you can skip your first article in loop

Comment: How to skip first article in loop?

Comment: write this code after loop if(!isset($skipFirst)){ $skipFirst=1; cotinue; }